# Facebook Login Button and redirect to offline webpage 'file:///xx/yy/zz.html'

Tags: facebook, mobile, authentication

I'm developing a mobile web application, simply I wanna add Facebook Login button to my page so the user can like items at the page.

When I use the Java SDK and the Login button tags it opens a popup and there is no way to set the display to touch instead of popup.

When I use the graph APIs and I can set the display to touch but cause I'm browsing my pages offline like this format "file:///xxx/www/index.html" Facebook throw invalid format error cause of that redirect URL is in the format above.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the Java SDK is just that. It won't register on touch. You should start by going through the Mobile Web Tutorial. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

All your problems will be long gone in no time. Best of luck